# Windows 10 Dual Boot Error

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, uefi

I am trying to set up two Windows 10 installations on the same machine (UEFI) using two separate NVMEs. I've followed the steps outlined in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-Gxj1N1oCc).

When booting up the original Windows 10 installation everything works fine, but when attempting to boot the second Windows 10 installation to set it up, I encounter the following issue.

> **Recovery** 
> Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
>
> The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a
> required file is missing or contains errors.
>
> File: `\windows\system32\winload.efi`
>
> Error code: `0xc000000e`

- I've tried running the following commands from WinRE, but it does not resolve the issue, nor does `/RebuildBCD` find any Windows installations, even though I can browse both of them:

  ```powershell
  BootRec /FixMBR
  BootRec /FixBoot
  BootRec /RebuildBCD
  ```
- ```powershell
  $ BcdEdit

      Windows Boot Manager
      --------------------
      identifier              {bootmgr}
      device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3
      path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
      description             Windows Boot Manager
      locale                  en-us
      inherit                 {globalsettings}
      default                 {current}
      resumeobject            {6d10e418-233a-11eb-a23c-38baf8825748}
      displayorder            {6d10e419-233a-11eb-a23c-38baf8825748}
                              {current}
      toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
      timeout                 5

      Windows Boot Loader
      -------------------
      identifier              {6d10e419-233a-11eb-a23c-38baf8825748}
      device                  partition=F:
      path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
      description             Windows 10 - Work
      locale                  en-us
      inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
      isolatedcontext         Yes
      allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
      osdevice                partition=F:
      systemroot              \Windows
      resumeobject            {6d10e418-233a-11eb-a23c-38baf8825748}
      nx                      OptIn
      bootmenupolicy          Standard

      Windows Boot Loader
      -------------------
      identifier              {current}
      device                  partition=C:
      path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
      description             Windows 10 - Personal
      locale                  en-US
      inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
      recoverysequence        {9844d6ef-2367-11eb-afba-b0a1b954a7fa}
      displaymessageoverride  Recovery
      recoveryenabled         Yes
      isolatedcontext         Yes
      allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
      osdevice                partition=C:
      systemroot              \Windows
      resumeobject            {9844d6ed-2367-11eb-afba-b0a1b954a7fa}
      nx                      OptIn
      bootmenupolicy          Standard
  ```
- ```powershell
  DISKPART> lis vol

    Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
    ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
    Volume 0     C                NTFS   Partition    931 GB  Healthy
    Volume 1     D                NTFS   Partition    232 GB  Healthy
    Volume 2                      NTFS   Partition    498 MB  Healthy
    Volume 3                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    Hidden
    Volume 4     E                NTFS   Partition    238 GB  Healthy
    Volume 5     F   ESD-USB      FAT32  Removable     14 GB  Healthy

  DISKPART> sel vol 3

  Volume 3 is the selected volume.

  DISKPART> det vol

    Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
    --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  * Disk 1    Online          232 GB  1024 KB        *

  Offline                : No

  DISKPART> sel vol 1

  Volume 1 is the selected volume.

  DISKPART> det vol

    Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
    --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  * Disk 1    Online          232 GB  1024 KB        *

  Read-only              : No
  Hidden                 : No
  No Default Drive Letter: No
  Shadow Copy            : No
  Offline                : No
  BitLocker Encrypted    : No
  Installable            : Yes

  Volume Capacity        :  232 GB
  Volume Free Space      :  195 GB

  DISKPART> sel vol 4

  Volume 4 is the selected volume.

  DISKPART> det vol

    Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
    --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  * Disk 2    Online          238 GB  1024 KB        *

  Read-only              : No
  Hidden                 : No
  No Default Drive Letter: No
  Shadow Copy            : No
  Offline                : No
  BitLocker Encrypted    : No
  Installable            : Yes

  Volume Capacity        :  238 GB
  Volume Free Space      :  228 GB
  ```

I doubt there is anything wrong with `%WinDir%\system32\winload.efi` on the second Windows 10 install, as I have applied the image multiple times using the commands from the video, also using the same image to perform multiple installations successfully before and after.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116113/discussion-on-question-by-megahertz-windows-10-dual-boot-error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries of making this work I ended up acquiring a larger drive and split it into two OS partitions. With this setup there were no issues implementing the dual-boot using the steps in the video mentioned in the original post.

Until someone confirms or denies whether dual-boot on a multi-disk setup is possible this is my best suggestion to anyone trying to set this up.